Why Sentry throws "Invalid token" (http status: 401) error for a valid token?
I've got a next.js application that connected to sentry and I'm confident about the token, But when I tried to run npm run build in my app to get output I faced Invalid token (http status: 401) error.
Note that npm run dev  has no problem!
Here's my .env.local  :
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL="something's here" 
NEXT_LOGGING_API_URL="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug 

and I also have withSentryConfig  in my next.config.js :
withSentryConfig(module.exports, { silent: true }, { hideSourcemaps: true })

I ran npm run build  and I faced this error:
error: API request failed
  caused by: sentry reported an error: Invalid token (http status: 401)
  DEBUG   2024-07-20 18:03:44.635547900 +03:30 skipping update nagger because session is not attended


Hope the token hasn't expired. Sometimes tokens have a limited validity period and I have experienced that but you can simply regenerate the Sentry token and update it in your environment variables.

Thank you for sharing your experience, But as I said, the token's completely valid

Can you explain to me what the ".sentryclirc" file is ???
